# Group displays/spaces in mission control

Tags: display, spaces, mission-control

Mission control has the binary options of either "Displays have separate spaces" or, if unchecked, all displays belong to the same virtual space (allowing you to have a window across 2+ montors).

Is there any third party method to allow e.g. displays 1 and 2 to have the same spaces, and monitor 3 belong to a different space?